# How to connect to pointbase database from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, database, jakarta-ee, database-connection

I am working on a project in which I need to connect to pointbase database from javascript. I do not have much knowledge about java script. Is it possible to connect to pointbase from java script? Please help me with a sample code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clear the doubts that `pointbase` is what? is it simple pointbase or pointbase database which comes with WebLogic Server of Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is for client side programming. If you mean you have a web interface you wish to connect to a server side database you need to use Server Side scripting (perl,php,asp...), you can then use [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to work with the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to connect to pointbase
>   from java script

Javascript is not Java Script.

Javascript is a client side language for manipulating webpages. It has almost no access to files (or databases).

You need a server side language, like Java for connecting to the database. You may want use [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) (You would need the drivers for the [Pointbase](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/db/pointbase.html#wp1058505)  database.

You can "call" this server side program from javascript. How you do depends on your architecture. Do you already have a Java web app (a Java EE app) running?

Answer (score 0):

javascript is not only a front end scripting language. It can be used by any javascript engine  though the typical usage is for front end code in a web browser. Java/.net/php are more natural fits for server side processing. There are server side engines that can run javascript:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions